# How to break 2D array definition in two lines without causing syntax error?

Tags: vba, syntax, syntax-error

I'm trying to improve readability by separating each sub-array in my 2D Array definition into a separate line but this is causing a syntax error. This is my code:

```
Dim Array2D As Variant
Array2D = [{"a","b";"c","d";"e","f"}]
```

And this is what I'm trying to do:

```
Dim Array2D As Variant
Array2D = [{ _
"a","b"; _
"c","d"; _
"e","f"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a semicolon before the first _ should work.

Dim Array2D As Variant

```
    Array2D = [{ ; _
    "a","b"; _
    "c","d"; _
    "e","f"}]
```

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it but I'm still getting a syntax error